# How to change multiple keys inside my dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a pretty complex dictionary and I would like to change the values of `Name` in `Entity1` to `Owner` and `Name` in `Entity2` in `Type`. I use below code but I got stuck....

`KeyError: 'Name'`

```
my_dictio = 
{'url': 'www.google.com', 'value': 
[{'Car': 'Mercedes', 'Engine': 'Hybrid', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'US', 'Name': 'Richard', 'Entity2': {'Name': 'type1', 'Payment': 'cash'}}},
{'Car': 'Audi', 'Engine': 'Hybrid', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'DE', 'Name': 'Mesut', 'Entity2': {'Name': 'type2', 'Payment': 'cash'}}}, 
{'Car': 'Volkswagen', 'Engine': 'Gas', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'FR', 'Name': 'Paul', 'Entity2': {'Name': 'type3', 'Payment': 'card'}}}]}

for i, dictionary in enumerate(my_dictionary['value']):
    my_dictionary['Origin'][i]['model'] = dictionary.pop('Name')
    
print(my_dictionary)
```

**This is my expected output:**

```
my_dictio = {'url': 'www.google.com', 'value': 
[{'Car': 'Mercedes', 'Engine': 'Hybrid', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'US', 'Owner': 'Richard', 'Entity2': {'Type': 'type1', 'Payment': 'cash'}}},
{'Car': 'Audi', 'Engine': 'Hybrid', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'DE', 'Owner': 'Mesut', 'Entity2': {'Type': 'type2', 'Payment': 'cash'}}}, 
{'Car': 'Volkswagen', 'Engine': 'Gas', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'FR', 'Owner': 'Paul', 'Entity2': {'Type': 'type3', 'Payment': 'card'}}}]}
```

Comment: Please provide also expected output (words might be misleading). Also you can also format your input not to be "long oneliner", but more structured and readable

Comment: @JanStránský I added the expected output and made it readable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
for d in my_dictionary['value']:
    d['Entity1']['Owner'] = d['Entity1']['Name']
    del d['Entity1']['Name']
    d['Entity1']['Entity2']['Type'] = d['Entity1']['Entity2']['Name']
    del d['Entity1']['Entity2']['Name']
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to drill down through it methodically -- it may help to use other variables for the sub-dictionaries (remember that they are references, so you can modify them and you will still be modifying the relevant elements of the original dictionary):

```
from pprint import pprint

my_dictio = {
    'url': 'www.google.com',
    'value': [{'Car': 'Mercedes',
               'Engine': 'Hybrid',
               'Entity1': {'Country': 'US',
                           'Entity2': {'Name': 'type1',
                                       'Payment': 'cash'},
                           'Name': 'Richard'}},
              {'Car': 'Audi',
               'Engine': 'Hybrid',
               'Entity1': {'Country': 'DE',
                           'Entity2': {'Name': 'type2',
                                       'Payment': 'cash'},
                           'Name': 'Mesut'}},
              {'Car': 'Volkswagen',
               'Engine': 'Gas',
               'Entity1': {'Country': 'FR',
                           'Entity2': {'Name': 'type3',
                                       'Payment': 'card'},
                           'Name': 'Paul'}}]}

pprint(my_dictio)

for d in my_dictio['value']:

    d1 = d['Entity1']
    d1['Owner'] = d1['Name']
    del d1['Name']

    d2 = d1['Entity2']
    d2['Type'] = d2['Name']
    del d2['Name']
    
pprint(my_dictio)
```

Comment: Looks very logical when you think about it. Well thank you! Seems like the same answer as below :)

Comment: @Mediterráneo There is clearly one basic overall approach, so yes, don't be surprised that it is pretty similar. It is not exactly the same because this assigns additional variables, rather than repeat the lookups of the same higher-level keys. However, both will work, and which is preferable is probably largely a matter of opinion. (The other one looks up `d['Entity1']` six times, which in my mind justifies creating another variable `d1`... but dictionary lookup is pretty cheap so it's not a huge issue.)

Comment: @Mediterráneo Specifically, if you were looking for a way to *rename* a key rather than creating a new one and deleting the old one, then I don't think that such a thing exists.